# Which train stations near the Oyster boundary have contactless validators on (train) platforms?

Tags: tickets, london, oyster-card, national-rail

On lines that have a London terminus, which stations have contactless validators easily accessible?

Because of how comparatively cheap contactless fares are, it can be advantageous when travelling into or out of London to use a combination of contactless and paper tickets... however that means needing to touch in and touch out.

For example, Riddlesdown has an on-platform validator easily accessible, meaning if you are close to the correct carriage it would be feasible to jump out, validate and jump back in... At Amersham, there are no validators on the platforms, but the ticket gates are very close to the middle of the London-bound platform, which would make it feasible to validate as well. Wimbledon, on the other hand, has validators only on tube platforms, which would make it infeasible to touch in/out from a train.

Is there a list of stations close to the contactless boundary that have validators easily accessible from the train platforms?

Comment: This sounds like a question for Geoff Marshall.

Comment: If you want to make one, the thing to use would be the national rail station plans, eg [Riddlesdown](https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations-and-destinations/stations-made-easy/riddlesdown-station-plan)

Comment: @MichaelHampton didn't expect to see his name on StackExchange!

Comment: @kiradotee I don't think he's on here. I could be mistaken, though. Someone ought to invite him to check out the question.

Comment: @AakashM Thank you, I did not realize that was available... that is fantastic. Now I wonder if that has been summarized in a table or API anywhere.

Comment: Also worth pointing out (not sure if this is on topic enough for an answer) that if you're using a Travelcard (season ticket) loaded onto your Oyster in combination with a paper ticket, and you're not using Oyster Pay as you Go (ie your paper ticket's validity starts where your Travelcard's validity ends), you do not need to touch in/out. Touching at both ends is only a strict requirement when using Pay as you Go Oyster, and though it's recommended in other cases, it's not required for this very reason.

Comment: @Muzer Unfortunately, my usage case does not involve a Travelcard - but rather, sporadic trips to multiple destinations on multiple lines.

Comment: I thought not, but I thought equally that someone else finding this question might not know that :)

Comment: @AakashM while that is a great resource for some lines, I am 99% sure I saw validators on the outbound platform of both Hounslow and Feltham yesterday, but they don't appear on the station plans.

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** a complete list, but [the list of stations set to "continuation exit" (unofficial site)](https://www.oyster-rail.org.uk/same-station-continuation-exits/) is a good starting point, although most stations are not 'boundary' stations and inclusion on the list does **not** guarantee a convenient validator on **every** NR platform:

- Barking [Zone 4]
- Chalfont & Latimer [Zone 8]
- Ealing Broadway [Zone 3]
- Elmers End [Zone 4]
- Farringdon [Zone 1]
- Finsbury Park LU [Zone 2]
- Harrow & Wealdstone [Zone 5]
- Harrow-on-the-Hill [Zone 5]
- Highbury & Islington [Zone 2]
- Kensington Olympia [Zone 2]
- Kentish Town [Zone 2]
- Moorgate [Zone 1]
- Old Street [Zone 1]
- Seven Sisters [Zone 3]
- South Ruislip [Zone 5]
- Stratford [Zones 2-3]
- Watford Junction [boundary station in its own special zone]
- West Croydon [Zone 5]
- West Ham [Zones 2–3] (there are Oyster/contactless readers are near the staircase)
- West Ruislip [Zone 6]
- Wimbledon [Zone 3] ([see this map (from the same unofficial site), which suggests that, as of July 2016, the platform for Thameslink services does have Oyster/contactless validators, but **not** the platform for South Western Railway services](https://www.oyster-rail.org.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Wimbledon-Oyster.jpg))
- Woolwich Arsenal DLR [Zone 4]

Another station, **not** on the above list, about which I happen to know:

- Upminster [Zone 6] (Upminster has standalone validators on platforms 2–3, which is convenient for c2c services heading **out** of London, since they are usually on platform 2; conversely, most c2c services heading **into** London use platform 1, which does **not** have standalone validators, although it does have a side entrance with a gateline).

Comment: +1 This is a great start... there is some overlap with my own partial list, though it does seem incomplete. Thanks.

Comment: Anon, can we change this answer into a community wiki? That way everybody is invited to add relevant information.